# covertJSONtoSQL returning empty values in NiFi

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi, processor

I am designing a work which takes a data from on database in MySQl to another database(MySQL) using **ExecuteSQL** processor followed up with **ConvertAvroToJson** then **ConvertJsonToSQL** then **PutSQL** as shown in below flow chart

[image: Flow diagram]

**ConvertJSONToSQL** returning the empty values like below

```
 INSERT INTO source_count (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The processor configuration is
[image]

what can be wrong in this workflow?

Comment: Generally convertJsonTosql returns like that only.You should configure sql relationship into putSQL processor but you give failure,original,sql into putSQL processor. Modify the relationship and check data going to which relationship?.It could resolve your problem

Comment: That worked!! I redirected fail,original relationship to convertJsontoSQL itself and SQL to putSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the answer given in the comments (to use the sql relationship with ConvertJSONToSQL), then if you have at least NiFi 1.2.0, you can replace everything after ExecuteSQL with [PutDatabaseRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/index.html). It lets you configure a reader (you would choose an [AvroReader](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.avro.AvroReader/index.html) that uses the Embedded Schema) and set the operation type to INSERT, and it will handle the SQL generation and execution for you.