# Duplicate records ingesting in incremental fetch using NIFI,

Tags: mysql, fetch, apache-nifi, processor

I am designing a workflow to get an incremental fetch using NIFI the source and target databases are in MySQL. the processors are **QueryDatabaseTable** and **spiltAvro** and **convertAvroToJson** and **convertJsonToSQL** and **PutSQL** as below image

[image]

and the configuration parameters for **querydatabasetable** is as follows

[image]

now the source database table has only 200 records, when I start the process the flow is ingesting the same records repeatedly.

I have set the **maximum-value columns** to *createTime* which is timestamp and the value for it is

```
2017-12-07 18:48:23
```

for all the 200 records.

I also replaced **maximum-value columns** with **ID** but that also resulted in same issue.
What could be causing this repeated ingestion?

Comment: What version of NiFi are you using and what database are you connecting to?

Comment: The version is 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion in the [covertJSONtoSQL returning empty values in NiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693683/covertjsontosql-returning-empty-values-in-nifi) by @mattyb I replaced **spiltAvro** and **convertAvroToJson** and **convertJsonToSQL** and **PutSQL** with **PutDatabaseRecord** processor, and it worked with Incremental ingestion.

The flow will look like this with **maximum-value columns** property has been set to ID,time_stamp

[image]